# Calculating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left |\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{1+\omega^2}\right|^2 d\omega$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to calculate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{1+\omega^2}\right|^2d\omega$$

I should use the substitution $\omega = \tan\theta$. Doing that gives me

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left |\frac{\cos(\tan\theta \cdot t)}{1+\tan^2\theta}\right|^2\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta$$

From here on I dont know what to do. For me it seems, the substitution didnt make things easier...

I would be grateful for any advice or hint!

Thank you.

Comment: Would you accept approaches that don't use that substitution?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, sure!

Comment: Assuming $t\in\Bbb R$, in theory the residue theorem (with which I've never been very good) gives the answer as$$2\pi i\lim_{\omega\to i}\frac{d}{d\omega}\left(\frac{\cos^2(\omega t)}{(\omega+i)^2}\right)=2\pi i\lim_{\omega\to i}\frac{d}{d\omega}\left(-\frac{2\cos^2(\omega t)}{(\omega+i)^3}-\frac{t\sin(2\omega t)}{(\omega+i)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\cosh^2t-t\sinh 2t\right),$$but Wolfram Alpha says the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}(1+(1+2|t|)\exp(-2|t|))$.

Comment: @J.G. You are on the right track, but note that for a fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\cos(ixt)=\cosh(xt)\to \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, so you can't close it with a semi circle and expect the integral to vanish. What you need to do is to use the fact that $2\cos(x)=\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)$, and use the linearity of the integral to get $2$ or $3$ (based on if you put the constant numerator into a different integral or not) and close the integrals with a semi circle based on the sign of $t$ (this is why we have the absolute value).

Answer (score 1):

Define $\operatorname{sgn}t:=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
0 & t=0\\
\frac{t}{\left|t\right|} & t\ne0
\end{array}\right.$. Following @Botond's comment, the integral is $$\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1+\exp(2i\omega t)}{(1+\omega^2)^2}d\omega,$$and an $R\to\infty$ semicircular contour above (below) the real axis encloses a second-order pole at $i\operatorname{sgn}t$ for $t\ne 0$ so the integrand doesn't diverge as $|\Im\omega|\to\infty$. In using the residue theorem, we need to include an overall $\operatorname{sgn}t$ factor based on the contour's orientation. If $t\ne 0$, the integral is $$\pi i\operatorname{sgn}t\lim_{\omega\to i\operatorname{sgn}t}\frac{d}{d\omega}\left(\frac{1+\exp(2i\omega t)}{(\omega+i\operatorname{sgn}t)^2}\right)\\=\pi i\operatorname{sgn}t\lim_{\omega\to i\operatorname{sgn}t}\left(-2\frac{1+\exp(2i\omega t)}{(\omega+i\operatorname{sgn}t)^3}+2it\frac{\exp(2i\omega t)}{(\omega+i\operatorname{sgn}t)^2}\right)\\=\frac{\pi}{4}(1+(1+2|t|)\exp(-2|t|)).$$The $t=0$ case is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, either by continuity or susbtituting $\omega=\tan u$, viz.$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2udu=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Nice :) ${}{}{}$